# jQuery week calendar: Not Loading the existing data in calendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, calendar

I am trying to use jQuery week calendar  https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki  to display the existing  meeting  on my webpage my problem is when the calendar is loading my events.php file is returning json data like

```
[{"id":"2","title":"Analytics","body":"Analytics","start":"2012-08-14 12:00:00","end":"60"},{"id":"8","title":"bvxc","body":"bvxc","start":"2012-08-17 12:00:00","end":"60"},{"id":"9","title":"anyp","body":"anyp","start":"2012-08-17 13:00:00","end":"60"},{"id":"16","title":"Analytbfn","body":"Analytbfn","start":"2012-08-17 10:45:00","end":"2012-08-17 12:30"},{"id":"17","title":"Analytbfn","body":"Analytbfn","start":"2012-08-16 08:00:00","end":"2012-08-16 10:15"},{"id":"18","title":"Analytbfn","body":"Analytbfn","start":"2012-08-18 07:30:00","end":"2012-08-18 11:00"}]
```

but these data are not loading in my calendar

Look at the http://dpaste.com/788236/  for my demo.js file 
Please tell me where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should return a JSON object with a property named "events" with its value set to the collection of events. Also the "end" parameter of the first three events is incorrect. It should indicate the end date+time of the appointment instead of the duration (60).

This will work:

```
{
 events: [{ "id": "2", "title": "Analytics", "body": "Analytics", "start": "2012-08-14 12:00:00", "end": "2012-08-14 13:00:00" }, { "id": "8", "title": "bvxc", "body": "bvxc", "start": "2012-08-17 12:00:00", "end": "2012-08-17 13:00:00" }, { "id": "9", "title": "anyp", "body": "anyp", "start": "2012-08-17 13:00:00", "end": "2012-08-17 14:00:00" }, { "id": "16", "title": "Analytbfn", "body": "Analytbfn", "start": "2012-08-17 10:45:00", "end": "2012-08-17 12:30" }, { "id": "17", "title": "Analytbfn", "body": "Analytbfn", "start": "2012-08-16 08:00:00", "end": "2012-08-16 10:15" }, { "id": "18", "title": "Analytbfn", "body": "Analytbfn", "start": "2012-08-18 07:30:00", "end": "2012-08-18 11:00"}]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use START ,END time in such a format

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

  EX : "start" :"2012-08-14T12:00:00"
       "end":"2012-08-14T13:00:00"
```